# pg_basebackup fails with " too many connections for role "replication""

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up a standby server and keep getting this error. My primary server has more than enough connections to handle the load:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 10
max_connections=100
checkpoint_segments = 8
wal_keep_segments = 8
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/archive/%f'
```

This is the command that fails on the standby server:

```
pg_basebackup -h ${MASTER_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR} -D ${PGDATA} -U ${REP_USER} -vPw --xlog-method=stream
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Sounds like someone might have set a connection limit at the user level. See [`ALTER ROLE ... CONNECTION LIMIT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterrole.html)

Comment: If you want to see settings for such you can dump globals and grep the username:

pg_dumpall -g |grep -i replication